# How do I install up to date version of emacs

Tags: apt, emacs

When I install emacs I run the following:

```
$ sudo apt-get emacs-gtk
$ emacs --version
GNU Emacs 26.1
```

I would like to use version 26.3

How can I install this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You haven't told us your release of Ubuntu, but it's only available via deb for Ubuntu 19.10, ie.

https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=emacs

shows the versions of emacs for each current release of Ubuntu.

You can also source the package via snaps, ie.

https://snapcraft.io/emacs

shows 26.3 available & packaged as a snap on 13-Sept-2019.

A `snap search emacs` will also find this

```
guiverc@d960-ubu2:~$   snap search emacs
Name             Version                           Publisher   Notes    Summary
emacs            26.3                              alexmurray  classic  GNU Emacs is the extensible self-documenting text editor
emacs-tealeg     ... etc (redacted)
```

shows it's availablility too, so a

`sudo snap install --classic emacs`

will install it.

*fyi: the --classic is required because of the confinement model chosen in packaging, ie. to allow greater ability of where you can load/save files when compared to normal snap confinement*